# CSS Button- Link only on text, not on button

Tags: css

I am making a CSS button to have as a widget. The `href` link only applies when hovered/clicked on the "Call Us" text, how do I get it to show on the whole button?

HTML:

```
<div class="mybutton"><a href="http://example.com">Call Us</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.mybutton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #214b83;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` element has `display:inline` by default so you can give `display:block;` and then give `height:100%;` and `width:100%;`. For centering the text, you need to give `line-height:80px;`(`height` of parent).

```css
.mybutton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #214b83;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.mybutton a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybutton"><a href="http://example.com">Call Us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the `.mybutton` style to your `<a>` element. You'll have to add `display: block` to the CSS rules to make it behave in the same way as a `<div>`, but that's all there is to it.

```css
 .mybutton {
   display:block;
   width: 200px;
   height: 80px;
   background-color: #214b83;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<a class="mybutton" href="http://example.com">Call Us</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .mybutton {
   width:200px;
   height: 80px;
   background-color:#214b83;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
 }

 .mybutton a{
   line-height: 80px;
   display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of elements in the HTML code:

```
<a href="http://example.com"><div class="mybutton">Call Us</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .mybutton {
   width:200px;
   height: 80px;
   background-color:#214b83;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
 }

 .mybutton a{
   line-height: 80px;
   display:block;
   color:#fff;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="mybutton"><a href="http://example.com">Call Us</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this it will work for you.

```
.mybutton a{
   line-height: 80px;
   display:block;
}
```